# How to prove a Proposition of Rouquier?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Proposition 7.15 in Rouquier's paper (see [Publication paper](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~rouquier/papers/dimension.pdf)) "Dimension of triangulated categories J. K-theory, 1 (2008) 193-256" as follows, for details please see Rouquier's paper (or [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.CT/0310134.pdf)):

``Let $A$ be  a noetherian finite dimensional $k$-algebra of global dimension $d\in \mathbf{N}\cup \{\infty\}$.
Assume $k$ is perfect. Then, $d$ is the minimal integer $i$ such that $A\mathrm{-perf}=\langle A\rangle_{i+1}$.''

I am trying to give a proof as follows:

1. If the global dimension is $\infty$, then Proposition 7.15 is hold.
2. Assume that the global dimension is finite. Denote by $min$ the minimal integer $i$ such that $A\mathrm{-perf}=\langle A\rangle_{i+1}$.

   (a) Proposition 7.4 and Proposition 7.25 implies   that $A\mathrm{-perf}=\langle A\rangle_{d+1}$, and this implies that $min\leq d$.

   (b) Suppose that there is an $A$-module $W$ such that $\mathrm{pdim}\,W\geq min+1$.
    Then Lemma 7.13 implies that $W\notin\langle\mathrm{ads}(A)\rangle_{min+1}$.
   **Then there should be a contradiction !**
   Hence, for any $A$-modules $W$, $\mathrm{pdim}\,W\leq min$, therefore  $d\leq min$.

Note that Lemma 7.13, Proposition 7.4 and Proposition 7.25 are in Rouquier's publication paper, for details please see Rouquier's paper.

**Q. What I don't understand is that why there is a contradiction?**

Comment: how can it be so that some statements in the text indicate that it's not clear how to prove some other statement in the same text?!

Comment: The paper is in [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.CT/0310134.pdf).

Comment: It might help if you gave a statement of the Proposition and explained what you do and don't understand about the proof.

Comment: If an edit such as Jeremy Rickard suggests is made I will vote to reopen. I think questions like this should be allowed in general, though obviously one has to give some background and point to where the difficulty lies

Comment: I am sorry for the first time edit!

Answer (score 5):

Since $W$ has finite projective dimension, it is isomorphic in the derived category to a bounded complex of projective $A$-modules.  Thus it belongs to $A$-perf = $\langle A \rangle_{min + 1}$.  That contradicts Lemma 7.13 as you stated in (b).

Comment: We know that objects in $A-perf$ are bounded complexes of finite generated projective A-modules, why $W \in A-perf$?

Comment: @ParksJonehan There is always a finitely generated (in fact, cyclic) module whose projective dimension is equal to the global dimension of the ring. So $W$ can be chosen to be finitely generated, in which case, if the global dimension is finite and the ring is noetherian, its minimal projective resolution is a bounded complex of finitely generated projectives, so $W$ is perfect.